# In a unix box, I am taking a list of files as input. If it is found, return the path otherwise return a message "filename file not found"

Tags: bash

I have used the `find` command for this, but it doesnt return any message when a file is not found.

And I want the search to be recursive and return a message "not found" when a file is not found.

Here's the code I have done so far. Here "input.txt" contains the list of files to be searched.

```
set `cat input.txt`
echo $@
for i in $@
do
find $HOME -name $i
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with using a script. I hope this will do.

```
#!/bin/bash -f
for i in $@
do
  var=`find $HOME -name $i`
  if [ -z "$var"]
  then
     var="File not found"
  fi
  echo $var
done
```

Comment: hey, this is considering only the last read file and not all the files

Comment: what does the "if [ x"$var" == x ]" do? i mean, what does it compare? In the version of unix i am using, == is an unknown operator and therefore i am having trouble in running the script

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
listfile=input.txt
exec 3>&1
find | \
  grep  -f <( sed 's|.*|/&$|' "$listfile" ) | \
  tee /dev/fd/3 | \
  sed 's|.*/\([^/]*\)$|\1|' | \
  grep  -v -f - "$listfile" | \
  sed 's/$/ Not found/'
exec 3>&-
```

- open file descriptor 3
- find the files
- see if they're on the list (use `sed` to
- send a copy of the found ones to file descriptor 3
- strip off the directory name
- get a list of the ones that don't appear
- add the "Not found" message
- close file descriptor 3

Output looks like:

```
/path/to/file1
/path/somewhere/file2
foo Not found
bar Not found
```

No loops necessary.

Comment: Great answer! Depending on your implementation of `find`, you may require a path (such as `.`) as a parameter: `find . | \ [...]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shell builtin ['test'](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/scrpt/scrpt2.5.html) to test the existence of a file.  There is also an alternative syntax using square brackets:

```
if [ -f $a ]; then     # Don't forget the semicolon.
    echo $a
else
    echo 'Not Found'
fi
```

Comment: Except this won't test recursively whether the file exists, which was a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way - create a list of all the files to grep against.  If your implementation supports
grep -q otherwise use grep [pattern] 2&>1 >/dev/null....

```
find $HOME -type f |
while read fname
do
    echo "$(basename $fname)  $fname"
done > /tmp/chk.lis
while read fname
do
   grep -q "^$fname" /tmp/chk.lis 
   [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "$fname found" || echo "$fname not found"
done < /tmp/chk.lis
```

All of this is needed because POSIX find does not return an error when a file is not found

Comment: You could pipe the first `while` into the second and eliminate the temporary file. This will fail if filenames contain spaces, though. You could eliminate the `basename` part and change your `grep` to `grep -q "/$fname\$". The real problem with this is that you're checking whether a list contains its own members.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -nlE'say-f$_?$_:"not found: $_"' file
```